# How to choose scopes for the Uber API?

Tags: uber-api

I've tried to access Uber API.
Couldn't find in the documentation where I can get the scopes API, because I can't access the API without it. Documentation send to the Oath page in the Developer's page, but there is no functionality there to choose a scope.

Would be very glad to any help.